# Some circular, repeated event handling here? But what and how?

Tags: c#, wpf

How can I avoid this warning message in VS2017 (or: what may be happening):

```
'ObsCol<T>.ObsCol()' contains a call chain that results in a call to a virtual method
defined by the class.
Review the following call stack for unintended consequences: 

ObsCol<T>..ctor()
ObservableCollection<T>.add_CollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler): Void
```

this is the code:

```
[Serializable]
public class ObsCol<T> : ObservableCollection<T> 
{
   public ObsCol()
   {
      this.CollectionChanged += new NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler(ObsCol_CollectionChanged);
   }       

   private void ObsCol_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
   {
       if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add)
       MainViewModel.IsDirty = e.NewItems != null || e.OldItems != null;

   }
}
```

The purpose of this all is to know in the ViewModel whether  or not the calculation output corresponds to the input data.
Upon entering the constructor, CollectionChanged is empty, so my handler is the only thing in the list.

Changing CollectionChanged does not change the collection, does it?

Things seem to work alright, though...

Comment: Why don't you override the [OnCollectionChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms654934(v=vs.110).aspx) method?

Comment: Post the code where this is used because I don't see anything wrong here... However, you can do this without having a static ViewModel which is bad. I'm assuming it's static or has a static IsDirty member by how you're calling it. I'm guessing where the code is used is the issue??

Comment: The CollectionChanged event is declared virtual, so shouldn't be used in a constructor, hence the warning.

Comment: Ah, good @Clemens.  I was thinking this was an interface and didn't pay attention to the inheritance.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182331.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The Problem: some subclass could override the event, leading to unexpected construction behavior

```
public class Boom<T> : ObsCol<T>
{
    public override event NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler CollectionChanged
    {
        add { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
        remove { }
    }
}
```

Solutions:

Use `OnCollectionChanged` override

```
public class Solution1<T> : ObservableCollection<T>
{
    protected override void OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add)
            DoSomething();

        base.OnCollectionChanged(e);
    }

    ...
}
```

Seal the class

```
public sealed class Solution2<T> : ObservableCollection<T>
{
    public Solution2()
    {
        this.CollectionChanged += new NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler(ObsCol_CollectionChanged);
    }

    ...
}
```

Seal the event

```
public class Solution3<T> : ObservableCollection<T>
{
    public sealed override event NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler CollectionChanged
    {
        add { base.CollectionChanged += value; }
        remove { base.CollectionChanged -= value; }
    }


    ...
}
```

What you do depends on your use case... the first solution is most flexible, since you can still create subclasses with all kinds of override.

With the `SerializableAttribute` in your question, it might be worth to seal the whole class since you probably don't want to serialize sub-types anyway (Solution 2).

If you are ever in a situation, where the `OnEvent`/`RaiseEvent` method is not available for whatever reason, Solution 3 allows to seal only the minimal subset of functionality that is used in the constructor.